# The displayed value is: C++

Tags: c++

I got this piece of code and I have to choose the correct answer.

```
int x = 5;
int* y = &x;
cout << *y << endl;
```

And now:

- a)y value raised to a power
- b)address of the cell in which x is located
- c)variable cell address y
- d)value 5

When I entered it in the program, I just popped out `5`, but I don't know if that's the right answer.

Comment: So, you compiled and ran the program but doubt that your output is correct? Why?

Comment: it is good to not rely on trial and error, because this can be terribly misleading (in the presence of UB), on the other hand it is not clear why you think 5 is not the right answer

Comment: Do you have a question about this?  You haven't asked us a question, which leaves us to guess what you want us to say.

Comment: The subject of the inquiry is a question.

Comment: This is a question for the school.

Comment: ok school, but the puzzling part is that they should have told you what it takes to answer before asking you such quizzes. What specifically do you not understand about the code?

Comment: I don't understand what is the address of a variable cell

Comment: There is not much to understand. _a variable cell_ is not really an official or C++ typical term (except the variable is called `cell` but that's not the case here).

Comment: I do not know why `cout << *y << endl;` resulted in the output `C++`.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, let's review this code, but you should get a good book and start it from the beginning.

```
int x = 5;
```

This defines a variable called x, and it has an initial value of 5.

```
int * y = &x;
```

This defines a variable called y. It's a pointer to an int, and it's current value is the location of x. If x is in memory location 1000, then y's current value is 1000.

```
cout << *y << endl;
```

This outputs the value that y points to. In this example so far, as y points to x, and x is 5, then the value is 5.

What's confusing is the `<<`. If you're accustomed to other languages, this doesn't necessarily do what you think. It's a big thing.

In C++, you can change the meaning of any operator based on what appears on either side. In this case, `cout` is an `ostream` -- output stream. Output streams define `operator<<` as meaning output, not a shift. So what you're doing is sending `5` to `cout`, and it prints it for you.

So there is no bitwise math happening here.

Comment: @NukaNuka56 Are you taking the exam right now?

Comment: @NukaNuka56 Looking at your question history, it certainly feels like you are in school and delegating quiz questions to Stack Overflow. You should be more worried about *why* an answer is correct rather than about which answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, that is a question from school.

Comment: @NukaNuka56 I think you need to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator too - or open your book on the page describing pointers. if it's a good book for beginners, it'll be in the back somewhere - otherwise it'll probably be on page 1.

Comment: Getting a degree gets your foot in the door. Not being able to back it with your own knowledge will get you ghosted every single time. Cheating always catches up.

Comment: @sweenish I have to wonder why someone would take programming then clearly hope for someone else to do the work for them.

Comment: Money. Same as med school and lawyering, but those have clear(er) methods of weeding people out. One thing I had partial issues with when I taught was the department's desire to both hold students' hands and push them toward their degree. Some of it was very good, like free tutoring, but there was that underbelly that showed itself every now and again about just having registration numbers and not sending them off to other programs like MIS.

Answer (score 0):

What this is doing is to create a variable `x`, point a pointer to it `y`, and output the value it points to `5`. If you were to change the value of `x`, you would see that same change reflected when you output `*y`.